# PHP ffmpeg trying to include a variable but it's not executing at all

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, php

I have the following variables set in PHP:

```
$ffmpeg = ffmpeg.exe;
$VideoFilename = "C:/Videos/VideoFile_1.mp4";
$CroppedVideoFilename= "C:/Videos/VideoFile_1_Cropped.mp4";
```

I have the following line of code in PHP:

```
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $VideoFilename -vf crop=848:352:4:64 $CroppedVideoFilename";
$Return = `$cmd`;
```

which seems to work well; it creates a cropped video.

However, the following will not work:

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg.exe -i $VideoFilename -vf crop=848:352:4:64 $CroppedVideoFilename";
```

or

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg.exe -i C:/Videos/VideoFile_1.mp4 -vf crop=848:352:4:64 $CroppedVideoFilename";
```

or

```
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i C:/Videos/VideoFile_1.mp4 -vf crop=848:352:4:64 C:/Videos/VideoFile_1_Cropped.mp4";
```

and especially what I'm trying to get going is:

```
$CroppingValues = "crop=848:384:4:32";
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $VideoFilename -vf $CroppingValues $CroppedVideoFilename";
```

I posted the other lines of faulty code because it might aid in solving as to "why" some variables are being accepted by ffmpeg command and others are not.

I would like to get the last block of code working. For some reason it's just not executing. I've been looking in to escaped characters and have tried:

```
$CroppingValues = "crop=848\:384\:4\:32"
```

which doesn't work but

```
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $VideoFilename -vf crop=848\:384\:4\:32 $CroppedVideoFilename";
```

Does work, and then the following:

```
$CroppingValues = "crop\=848\:384\:4\:32"
```

doesn't work so there's something wrong with the `$CroppingValues` variable.

## Update:

Just discovered `$CroppingValues` has a `\n` new line in it.

Answer (score 1):

It was the "\n" New Line break within the $CroppingValues variable.

Full code:

```
Function GetStringBetween($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

and

```
$CroppingValues = GetStringBetween($returnnn, "crop=", "[");
if(strstr($CroppingValues, "\n")) 
{
    $CroppingValues = str_replace("\n", "", $CroppingValues);
}
else
{
    echo 'There is no Line Break detected.';
}
if(strstr($CroppingValues, "\n")) 
{
    echo 'There is still a Line Break detected';
}
else
{
    echo 'There is no Line Break detected';
}
```

So be careful not to include any Line Breaks within your variables whilst executing commands via `$cmd` and with ffmpeg.exe.